# style listing wordpress 2 custom post types and 1 taxonomie

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have developed a directory of suppliers based on 2 custom post types, sharing the same taxonomy, so good, in my home page I display a list of terms for access by registered advertisers, just like

[Screenshot 1](http://anaranja.com/grabs/anaranja-EiMe.png)[image]

and all is well .... but....

**Here starts the problem.**

**I get a page with the list of registered advertisers in any of the custom post types but I would like that depending on the custom post type each listing has its style ...**

[Screenshot 2](http://anaranja.com/grabs/anaranja-RPfV.png)[image]

A style for custom post type named "directorio" and a different style for custom post type named "basico" the shared taxonomy is called "categoria"

In the screenshot 2, sample... Oscar Navarro has been registered in custom post type "basico" and "Carlos Galarza Fotografía" has been registered in custom post type "directorio".

Is posible add classes to each custom post type for styling different in css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the post type in the loop and add class to that post

Please check the content template_part

Trying modifying the template part like below

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
global $post;
                <span id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>


            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('large');?>
            </a>
        </span>


<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Add this to function.php

```
add_filter( 'post_class','your_post_class' , 20, 3 );

    public function your_post_class( $classes, $class, $post_id ) {
        if ( 'basico' == get_post_type() ){
               $classes[] = 'basico_class';
            }elseif ( 'directorio' == get_post_type()){
               $classes[] = 'directorio_class';
            }
        return $classes;
}
```

Comment: as...

<?php if ( 'basico' == get_post_type() ){
     get_template_part( 'style', 'basico' );
}elseif ( 'directorio' == get_post_type()){
     get_template_part( 'style', 'directorio' );
}?>

this code look for... style-basico.php and style-directorio.php ???

TNXS!

Comment: you cannot do like that..Inside the  get_template_part() you need to check the post_type.not before .... Looping starts inside the get_template_part();